# Moving div to bottom on mobile screens

Tags: css, media

I would like to move a div to the bottom on mobile screen, my website uses blocks in the sidebar and I would like to move them to bottom when someone uses a small device

I have had some success hiding the sidebar blocks on mobile devices but moving them as been frustrating

Some stuff still showed on mobiles because the blocks are made up with 4 divs so i put all code in a div `myblock-hide` this works with hiding the blocks

```
   $blockId = 'b-' . sha1($caption);
   print("<div class='myBlock-hide'>
      <div class='myBlock'>
        <div class='myBlock-caption'>$caption<a style='float:right; clear:right;' href='#' class='showHide' id='$blockId'></a></div>
        <div class='myBlock-content'>
        <div class='slidingDiv$blockId'>");
            print("</div>");
}
```

This hides on mobile devices. Is there a way possible to move it to bottom?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 430px) {
  .myBlock-hide {
      display: none;
  }
}
```

Maybe i could approach this a different way and hide parts of the table

```
  <!-- Start response -->
  <div id='main'>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="7" width="100%" border="0">
     <tr>
          <!-- START LEFT COLUM -->
          <td valign="top" width="170">
          <?php leftblocks();?>
          </td>
          <!-- END LEFT COLUM -->

          <!-- START MAIN COLUM -->
          <td valign="top">
          <?php function_exists('T_') or die;
            if ($site_config["MIDDLENAV"]){
                middleblocks();
            } // MIDDLENAV ON/OFF END
            ?>
          </td>
          <!-- END MAIN COLUM -->

          <!-- START RIGHT COLUMN -->
          <td valign="top" width="170">
          <?php rightblocks(); ?>
          </td>
          <!-- END RIGHT COLUMN -->
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<!-- End response -->
```

Comment: You can try  position: absolute; bottom: 0;  on .myBlock-hide. Or, if it should remain on the bottom all the time, use position: fixed; bottom: 0; instead

Comment: Note that the HTML attributes you are using  are obsolete. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `position: fixed` and `bottom: 0`

> also you can remove the `<div class="myBlock-hide"> ... </div>`

**For example**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .myBlock {
      position: fixed;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: 40; // greater value keep it above all
      width: 100%; // or your desired width
  }
}
```

Comment: thats almost got it, except it shows all blocks on top of each other at the bottom

Comment: use `z-index` to get them to the top the value will be based on other elements `z-index` Check my updated answer

Comment: better but still showing on top of each other, i also tried hiding parts of table (see above post) with no luck not sure if that is a better way, the plan this way was to have the two sideblocks hidden on mobiles but then put the same code in the footer hiding on desktop, i think the problem is adjustable blocks when placing them on bottom all center,left and right go down there

Comment: create a runnable code here / `jsFiddle` / `stackbliitz` to recreate your issue, and with that surely can help you..